# How to get an intent extra in a fragment from another activity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am trying to get `Extras` in the fragment from an activity with the following code. It was working without errors when I add the code in the `onCreateView()` however, it was giving a null. Then I moved the block of code to the `onCreate()` but the app crashes error  `Error inflating class fragment`. I have googled for it and I couldn't find an answer for `Kotlin`.

Following is the code in the `fragment`

```
    if (activity?.intent!!.hasExtra("ServiceArea")) {
        productList = activity?.intent!!.getStringArrayExtra("ServiceArea").toString()
    }
```

Following is the code in the activity that sends extras.

```
val intent = Intent(this, DashboardFragment::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("ServiceArea", "allArea")
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        this.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Try to use bundle arguments for fragment to  f.setArguments(args) from where you need and then getbundle and get data.hope it may help you. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment

Comment: Can you just show me how can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi please check answer for the way you want

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way may help you, if you want exactly this in your task then you can use

First get the extras inside activity

In parent activity of Fragment

```
if (activity?.intent!!.hasExtra("ServiceArea")) { 

   areastring = activity?.intent!!.getStringExtra("ServiceArea").toString()
 }
```

Then for fragment Instance with bundle from parent activity

```
fragment manager.add with 
newInstance(areastring)

static CountingFragment newInstance(String area) { 
   CountingFragment f = new
   CountingFragment(); 
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putString("area", areastring);
   f.setArguments(args); 
    return f; 
}
```

In Fragment get by using this method

```
bundle.getArgunents to get value
```

Or another way directly you can use this extras value by parent activity object in fragment
or pass the arguments object directly inside constructor of fragment when create and then use in fragment.

**In kotlin**

```
Companion object{
   fun newInstance(String area) :   CountingFragment {
     var f:CountingFragment = CountingFragment(); 
     var args =  Bundle();
     args.putString("area", areastring);
      f.setArguments(args); 
      return f; 
 }
```

}

Comment: I asked for `Kotlin`, it doesn't seem to work in `Kotlin`

Comment: Hi please just try this way for problem you facing, convert it,  in kotlin method and way of process is not different in java and kotlin, when you copy and paste java code in kotlin file it will popup to convert in kotlin so try please. Hope it may help you

Comment: Android Studio didn't show the pop us to convert the code when I copy & paste this, since I did not understand the second set of code I am not able to convert it myself.

Comment: @Codist now please check I have updated answer in kotlin, you just need to update like that hope it may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
productList = activity?.intent?.getStringExtra("ServiceArea").toString()
```